# MongoDB C++ driver handling replica set connection failures

Tags: c++, mongodb

So the mongo c++ documentation says

> On a failover situation, expect at least one operation to return an
>   error (throw an exception) before the failover is complete. Operations
>   are not retried

Kind of annoying, but that leaves it up to me to handle a failed operation. Ideally I would just like the application to sleep for a few seconds (app is single threaded). And retry with the hopes that a new primary mongod is established. In the case of a second failure, well I take it the connection is truly messed up and I just want to thrown an exception.

Within my MongodbManager class this means all operations have this kind of double try/catch block set up. I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution?

Example method:

```
template <typename T>
std::string
MongoManager::insert(std::string ns, T object)
{
  mongo::BSONObj = convertToBson(object);
  std::string result;
  try {
    connection_->insert(ns, oo); //connection_ = shared_ptr<DBClientReplicaSet>
    result = connection_->getLastError();
    lastOpSucceeded_ = true;
  }
  catch (mongo::SocketException& ex)
  {
    lastOpSucceeded_ = false;
    boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::seconds(5) );
  }

  // try again?
  if (!lastOpSucceeded_) {
    try {
      connection_->insert(ns, oo);
      result = connection_->getLastError();
      lastOpSucceeded_ = true;
    }
    catch (mongo::SocketException& ex)
    {
       //do some clean up, throw exception
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Have the same issue with the C# driver...wondering if try/catch/retry is just a necessary evil...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's indeed sort of how you need to handle it. Perhaps instead of having two try/catch blocks I would use the following strategy:

- keep a count of how many times you have tried
- create a while loop with as terminator (count < 5 && lastOpSucceeded)
- and then sleep with pow(2,count) to sleep more in every iteration.

And then when all else fails, bail out.